# Why/when does Django makemigrations ignore a field and then do an Add field or Alter

Tags: django, django-models

This is the order Django created the migration

```
- Create model MedicalTest
- Create model MedicalTestGroup
- Add field test_group to medicaltest
- Alter unique_together for medicaltest (1 constraint(s))
```

This is the order I was expecting

```
- Create model MedicalTestGroup
- Create model MedicalTest
```

Under what circumstances would it do what I am expecting?

Why does it only get some of the ordering wrong some of the time?

I understand and acknowledge that the outcome of both may be the same. I am asking what might cause Django to treat the order of one model differently from another because I'd like to get it right in my own code.

Comment: Based on what did you expect following order below? What do you mean by it gets some of ordering wrong some of time? It simply depends on models relation and alphabetical order

Comment: MedicalTest has a ForeignKey to MedicalTestGroup. MedicalTestGroup SHOULD have been created first like everything else that was higher on the dependency does. It did not. Why?

Comment: It will work top to bottom iirc, that makes sense: yes there is a dependency, but there an be models with mutual dependencies, so there is no (guaranteed) topological sorting.

Comment: My confusion comes from not understanding where I think there is obvious topological sorting but Django doesn't. I want to understand that gap because it may well mean that there is a better way to define the models.